Qualtrics: Dynamically updating embedded data based on selected response
I am trying to dynamically update an embedded field "Measurements" based on respondent selections in Q21 (a multi select question) and corresponding numerical inputs from Q178 (a numerical form field question with display logic dependent on Q21).
Basically I want to generate a list of all the respondent's selections from Q21, pair those selections with numerical inputs, and display that list in a clean format as part of a new question using Javascript.
I have tried accomplishing this with piped text natively in Qualtrics but have not been successful. Since many respondents will only be selecting a handful of answers from Q21, when I create a simple list of piped text fields in my new question, the fields for answers not selected in Q21 show up as "0" which doesn't make sense in the context of the question. Anything not selected in Q21 should not show up in the new question at all.
I have also tried to execute this using embedded data updated natively in Qualtrics survey flow without success. For each possible response in Q21, I created a binary embedded data field - 1) The answer label (if the answer was selected) and 2) blank (if the answer was not selected). I then added a list of the Q21 binary embedded data fields into my question. However, with this approach many of the "rows" in the list come up blank and the display looks strange.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I attached the following Javascript to Q178, which has display logic dependent on Q21.
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageSubmit(function() {
var input1Value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('InputQID178_1').value);
var input2Value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('InputQID178_2').value);
var input3Value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('InputQID178_3').value);
var input4Value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('InputQID178_4').value);
var input5Value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('InputQID178_5').value);

var selectedChoices = Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getQuestionInfo('QID21').getSelectedChoices();
var meas = Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData('Measurements');

if (selectedChoices.includes('1')) {
    meas += "<br>" + input1Value + " " + "Q21 Label 1";
}
if (selectedChoices.includes('2')) {
    meas += "<br>" + input2Value + " " + "Q21 Label 2";
}
if (selectedChoices.includes('3')) {
    meas += "<br>" + input3Value + " " + "Q21 Label 3";
}
if (selectedChoices.includes('4')) {
    meas += "<br>" + input4Value + " " + "Q21 Label 4";
}
if (selectedChoices.includes('5')) {
    meas += "<br>" + input5Value + " " + "Q21 Label 5";
}

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Measurements', meas);

});

